# In Vert.x web client, can I map a JSON response to a collection of POJOs?

Tags: java, json, vert.x, vertx-httpclient

In Vert.x [Web client manual](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/#_decoding_responses) there's an example of decoding an incoming JSON response into a POJO:

```
client
  .get(8080, "myserver.mycompany.com", "/some-uri")
  .as(BodyCodec.json(User.class))
  .send(ar -> {
      // Process the response
   })
```

Is there a way to decode an incoming JSON array into a collection of objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe you can use a `BodyCodec` to convert the content straight to a collection of objects.

However you use Vert.x core `Json` class with the body as `Buffer`

```
client
  .get(8080, "myserver.mycompany.com", "/some-uri")
  .send(ar -> {
    if (ar.succeeded()) {
      Buffer body = ar.result().body();
      List<User> users = Json.decodeValue(body, new TypeReference<List<User>>() {});
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  });
```