# How to, in vert.x, define a default codec for a collection?

Tags: java, kotlin, vert.x, vertx-eventbus

Assuming I have a class named `User`, can I register a codec for a collection of `User`s?

I tried using just this:

```
eb.registerDefaultCodec(List<User>::class.java, User.UserListCodec())
```

But it produces this error: Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal.

Comment: You can't unfortunately. You must either create a `UserList` object or simply get the message as a buffer and convert with Jackson type ref (see similar issue with WebClient https://stackoverflow.com/a/53812159/2133695). In Vert.x 4 this shall be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `arrayListOf(...)`

```
eb.registerDefaultCodec(arrayListOf<User>()::class.java, User.UserListCodec())
```